# Calling database upon ToList() method call

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.2

From my repository I return different List using ToList() method.

The problem is when I run some more LINQ on this returned result (i.e. of type List) it generates a database call for this too. Apparently this second linq calll is pure LINQ to Entity and database should not be called. See below what I am doing.

```
List<User> us = userRepository.GetMany(u => filterStatusIds.Contains(u.UserStatus.Id));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
us = (from u in us
      where u.DisplayName.Contains(name)
      select u).ToList(); // this ToList should not call database
```

Any help or idea to stop this additional database calls?

Comment: Why do you think it executes database query again? Also why do you execute filter in your application instead of the database?

Comment: @abatishchev: The first call to `ToList` will switch to linq-to-objects and there is no way back because the result is materialized and expression tree is gone.

Comment: @Ladislav: Sure, you're right, have misread your initial comment.

Answer (score 1):

Return `IEnumerable<User>` or `IQueryable<T>` from repository, it will not query the database.

Only second call will do this, after ToList().

Comment: out of interest - does it mean that in the first query the return type of `List<User>` forces an enumeration of the results ? I.e. it's not just some sort of a cast between `IEnumerable` and `List` but it involves the materialization of the results (the `ToList()` is implicit) ? That should probably be obvious to me, but I would be happy if you can confirm.

Comment: I tried a simple example with List<int> which I filtered and without the call to `ToList` the compiler just told me that IEnumerable cannot be converted to a list implicitly. Is that different in this example ? How does it work in the first line of the example ?

Comment: @Joanna: Yes, calling ToArray()/ToList() causes materialization. So if method returns just IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T> "as is", no materialization occurs. After first m-z you switch from LINQ to Entities to LINQ to Objects, i.e. load first filtering result into server memory and enumerate it into memory in every next filter.

Comment: @Joanna: So if you want to return non-materialized data, don't call m-z methods on return/query, and "simplify" return type, to match.

Comment: @Joanna: imo, that's understandable and useful in case of LINQ to Database, but much less in LINQ to XML. I've fallen into a trap with it once.